# How to filter the Eclipse Outline View to show only Functions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I want to have the 'Outline view' in Eclipse in the CDT (so for a C project) show me only function names. So no enums, include files, macros, etc...

There are some options in the 'Filters...' menu, but none that make it possible to only show functions.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 7):

You could use the "group Includes" and "group Macros" from the drop-down menu of the outline view to limit the list. (they will each be folded into a separate folder)

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody's answered yet I'll offer this. 
Step 1. Display the Members view. (menu Window > Show View > Other, then under "Java" select "Members")
Step 2. At the upper right, toggle icons to filter the display. For example, turn on "Hide Fields" and "Hide Local Types." You can also filter out static objects and non-public members.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I now realize that my original question wasn't clear enough, because I'm not using Java, but C. I updated the question (not sure if I'm going to get any answers on this, but still....)

Comment: Actually it's  window->show view->java browsing->members, but otherwise: nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to hide the includes by creating a Filter(Can be found in the DropDown Menue Filters):
E.g. if you do not want to see C,C++ Include Files: "*.h, *.hpp" would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on 'Hide Fields' (third option in picture) to display just the functions (Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11))[image]